# HTML / Javascript: On Click Enable/UnDisable Input Fields?

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

I have the following HTML input boxes:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" disabled>
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" disabled>
<input type="text" name="3" id="3" disabled>
<input type="text" name="4" id="4" disabled>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit>
</form>
```

Next I am trying to use javascript to undisable all my input boxes upon a user clicking my div.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('#edit').click(function(){
        $('input[]').prop('disabled', false);
});
</script>
```

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong, thanks

Comment: there is actually no `div` nor `#edit` element in your sample code...

Comment: you are using `jquery` in your sample code

Answer (score 5):

The error is the selector, try:

```
 $('input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit').click(function(){ 
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
});
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" disabled>
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" disabled>
<input type="text" name="3" id="3" disabled>
<input type="text" name="4" id="4" disabled>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="edit">Click to Enable</div>
```

whenever using jquery coding before you must write **$(document).ready(function(){})**

Comment: be carefull that from where I see it attaching click event on elements that aren't supposed to be clicked might present a usability issue for people using screen-readers...

Answer (score 1):

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v22mchsh/)

```
 $('#edit').click(function(){
        $('input').prop('disabled', false);
 });
```

You can also use the `removeAttr` and the `attr` to add and remove the disabled

```
$('input').removeAttr("disabled");
$('input').attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('input:text').prop('disabled', false);
```

Or

```
 $('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Better to use `$('input[type=text]')`. cfr [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery 1.6+**

To change the disabled property you should use the .prop() function.

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

The **`.prop()`** function doesn't exist, but .attr() does similar:

Set the disabled attribute.

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again, the proper method is to use **`.removeAttr()`**

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```